# In ASP.NET, can CSS/JS files be combined if they're included at different levels of the Masterpage hierarchy?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, master-pages, umbraco

I have a complex Masterpage hierarchy that contains the templates for multiple sub-sites running within a single ASP.NET web application (Umbraco, in this case).  Each level of this hierarchy will have CSS and JavaScript, with some being at the base and some being sub-site level and some in between.  Sometimes we will override scripts and styles (overriding an old version of jQuery, for example) but most of the time we need to build upon established styles and scripts. Essentially, we're trying to optimize what the client receives so they're not getting overly bloated code from a site they're not even on, while keeping things somewhat maintainable.  Is there a way to combine CSS and Scripts when they are included at different levels of you Masterpage hierarchy?

Comment: You want both granularity and bundling at the same time?

Comment: Yes. I want to be able to have seperate CSS files, maintainable in the Umbraco back-office, but have them compiled based on their usage in the Masterpage templates.

Comment: If you were using v4.10 or upward, you might want to define a section in your main view and call that in the sub views to add scripts etc depending on the page you're on.